# Is there a particular behavior with fetch and pushState?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, pushstate, html5-history

I am having an issue trying to fetch some datas using pushState.

So i basically have 4 functions:

- an event listener on click
- a function to grab the link needed
- a function to trigger an animation
- and a function to fetch this url

Everything works fine until i try to push a state in the history.

history.pushState before, or after my fetch request, breaks the request like so: controller/controller/about.php for some reason.

I tried a console.log(url); on all 4 functions and the result is the same (a good url to fetch: controller/about.php for example)

I tried history.pushState inside my fetch request and it works fine (loads controller/about.php for example) but i need to work with the popstate event and call the same fetch function again.

My summarized code:

```
const loadNewContent = async url => {
    const response = await fetch(url, { headers: headers });
    // Tried adding pushState inside fetch request
    // window.history.pushState(url, `${url}`, url);
};

// function that fires animations then load the last function
const changePage = url => {
    loadNewContent(url).catch(error => console.error(error));;
};

const ajax = e => {
    // Tried adding pushState before fetch fires
    // window.history.pushState(newPage, ``, newPage);
    changePage(newPage);
    // Tried adding pushState after fetch fires
    // window.history.pushState(newPage, ``, newPage);
};

// Click event fires ajax function
ajax(e);
```

Comment: What is the URL of the page before and after you call `pushState`?

Comment: If i call pushState just before changePage(newPage); the url is controller/article.php but fetch returns a 404 trying to access controller/controller/article.php

Comment: If i call pushState just after changePage(newPage); same behavior

Comment: I think you misunderstand. What is the URL in the address bar of the browser before and after you call `pushState`?

Comment: Before: root (localhost/folder) after: localhost/folder/controller/article.php

Comment: That's really unclear. What is the **full** URL displayed in the address bar before and after you call `pushState`?

Comment: Ok, so before i call pushState the full url is: http://localhost/imparfait/ after i call pushState the full url is: http://localhost/imparfait/controller/article.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just how relative paths work. Everything after the last `/` is discarded, and the relative URL is appended.

`http://localhost/imparfait` + `controller/about.php` becomes `http://localhost/controller/about.php`

while

`http://localhost/imparfait/controller/article.php` + `controller/about.php` becomes `http://localhost/controller/controller/about.php`

Use an absolute path (starting with `/`), a scheme-relative URL (starting with `//localhost`), an absolute URL (starting with `http://`), or construct a URL using [the URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) which would let you specify the `base` instead of `fetch` getting it from `location.href`.

Comment: Oh, it was that simple! Thank you for your help and your patience @Quentin